# Providing Read Access to Google Cloud Storage Bucket with Access Token from Firebase Authentication Flow (for Mapbox GL Vector Tile Hosting)

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage, mapbox-gl-js, google-authentication

My app uses firebase authentication, and only users from my G Suite Domain are successfully authenticated. I have the scopes set as follows:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user')
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly')
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
```

My understanding is that I can use the access token that is returned from the above login flow for http requests to read objects from my Google Cloud Storage bucket. I insert the access token as a header like so:

`Authorization: 'Bearer xyz123'`

For my non-public bucket, I have Uniform bucket-level access enabled, with an IAM role that allows users from my G Suite domain to read from the bucket.

However, this isn't working, as I'm getting 403 responses for the http requests. For a little more context, I'm hosting vector tiles in the bucket which are being consumed by mapbox-gl.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

P.S. I am confident that this is a permissions problem and not a problem with mapbox config or the vector tiles themselves. When I make the bucket completely public, everything works just fine. What I'm struggling with is how to limit access to the vector tiles to only users within my G Suite domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did above was correct. However, I was missing one piece: the cors setting for my Google Cloud Storage bucket needed to be updated to replace

```
origin: "*"
```

with

```
origin: ["https://domain-name-where-request-comes-from.com", "https://and-dev-site-for-that-domain.com"]
```

Per the REST spec, the * wildcard is *not* acceptable when credentials are expected as part of the request.

I also needed to update the responseHeader of my cors settings:

```
"responseHeader": ["X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type", "Authorization"]
```

With the OAuth token inserted in the headers of the mapbox-gl request (via the transformRequset method), I could successfully request and receive the tiles.